# Jquery, outputting two bits of information from a object/array into one alert box

Tags: arrays, json, loops, object, for-loop

Afternoon, new to jquery, reading Jon Duckett's book and though very useful stuck trying to output a simple alert. What I want to do is output **title1** and **title2** in the same alert box.

I've also tried $.each() but with no luck and slightly less understanding.

```
    var json = {"myalert":[{"id":"1","title1":"Test1","title2":"Test1 - second"},{"id":"2","title1":"Test2","title2":"Test2  - second"}]}


    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){

    alert(json["myalert"][i].title1,  json["myalert"][i].title2);

    }
```

Apart from possibly incorrect syntax am I heading totally down the wrong route? Alert box pops up only displaying title1. If I output into HTML however it shows title1 twice!

Thanks, James

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want using a single loop:

```
var json = {"myalert":[{"id":"1","title1":"Test1","title2":"Test1 - second"},{"id":"2","title1":"Test2","title2":"Test2  - second"}]};
var alertText = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
  alertText += json["myalert"][i].title1 + ' ' + json["myalert"][i+1].title2;  
}
alert(alertText);
```

Or you can do the same thing without a loop:

```
var json = {"myalert":[{"id":"1","title1":"Test1","title2":"Test1 - second"},{"id":"2","title1":"Test2","title2":"Test2  - second"}]};
var alertText = json["myalert"][0].title1 + ' ' + json["myalert"][1].title2;
alert(alertText);
```